# Porting SQL/plPGsql tests to Java/JDBC: test an exception

Tags: java, postgresql, testing, jdbc

I'm porting database schema tests from sql/plpgsql to Java/JDBC. But here is a test case I can't figure out how to test. As I can guess, this test tries to insert some row to a table, and expects SPECIAL_EXCEPTION to be thrown. If it's thrown, the test passes, if other exception or no exception is thrown, the test fails. So the question: in the perspective of java.sql.Connection/Statement/ResultSet how to precisely test this?

```
begin;
do language plpgsql $$
declare
begin
    begin
        INSERT INTO table (
            name,
            blah...
        ) VALUES (
            'Test Player ',
            blah...
        );
    exception
        when sqlstate 'SPECIAL_EXCEPTION' then
            return;
        when others then
            raise info 'exception SPECIAL_EXCEPTION failed, invalid sqlstate';
            raise;
    end;
    raise exception 'exception SPECIAL_EXCEPTION failed, no error thrown';
end;
$$;
commit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, then what you want is:

```
   try {
      statement.executeUpdate();
   } catch(SQLException e) {
      if (!se.getSQLState().equals("SPECIAL_EXCEPTION") ) {
            fail();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I guess, this doesn't check if the exception is NOT thrown.

Comment: You can just throw a new Exception just after the executeUpdate row. The control will only reach it if the above line do not throws SQLException.

Comment: Sure. This is just a direction. The full logic you have to implement yourself.